# Work around immutable datetime to add a day in a loop

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to increment a datetime in a loop.

the datetime itself is not mutable, so when I call AddDays() I have to use a different variable.

But doing so, then the new variable, wich is a datetime, will be unmutable, so I need to crate a new variable to add yet another day, and so on.

How do you actually make a loop where you add a day every time, without create a new variable every time?

```
public void AddDayToDate()
{
    public DateTime startingdate = new DateTime(2016,1,1);
    public DateTime updated_date;
    while (true)
    {
        updated_date = startingdate.AddDays(1);
        print(updated_date);
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable/field is mutable. The struct contents are immutable. You can overwrite the whole struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You nearly had it:

```
public DateTime startingdate = new DateTime(2016,1,1);
public void AddDayToDate()
{
    var updatedDate = startingDate;
    while (true)
    {
        updatedDate = updatedDate.AddDays(1);
        print(updatedDate);
    }
}
```

Your use case is not too clear to me, but it's also perfectly valid to modify the original date as well:

```
public DateTime startingdate = new DateTime(2016,1,1);
public void AddDayToDate()
{
    while (true)
    {
        startingdate = startingdate.AddDays(1);
        print(startingdate);
    }
}
```

As for the question about mutability; You are *supposed* to create a new object (and possibly a new variable) every time you change a date. It's designed that way, and there's no real work-around (at least none that wouldn't be hacky).

Dates don't change. February 12th 2016 will *never* be February 13th 2016. A particular date you are referring to, however, *can* change - which is the same as changing the variable to a new date.

If you plan an event on February 12th 2016, and decide to move it to February 13th 2016, would you logically *change February 12th to forever be February 13th*, or would you simply give the event a new date?

Comment: I see; so it is possible to write on the same variable, the output of the AddDays. Thanks!